# Wordpress Scripts Being Loaded in Footer

Tags: php, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I've bought a theme for a Wordpress site.

I noticed that the theme author has added the javascript to the footer for load time, but as I use Gravity forms, I understand that some of scripts need to be in the head.

I don't know anything about enqueue or which scripts to put into the head, all I know is the majority of the scripts are currently in the footer.

As far as I'm aware all the scripts are being registered/enqueued from the functions.php file and this is causing me a real headache.

What information do I need to provide to have a little help?